# Problem with running Efficient search on a DB table based on multiple permutations

Tags: sql, search, database-design

I have a table with StudentId to subject mapping and below are the two possible schema's

DB: RDBMS

schema1:

| StudentId | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | b |
| 4 | c |

schema2:

| StudentId | Subjects |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b |
| 2 | a, c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | b, c |

Constraints:
The maximum number of subjects  that a student can subscribe to can be 10. The total number of subjects available are ~50.

**Use Case:**

I would like to filter students  subscribed to a list of subjects, only those requested subjects and nothing outside.
Eg: if I look for students subscribed to subjects a,b then the result should only include students subscribed to a,b or a or b. not a,c or b,c
If I run this search in the sample schema provided above then

Expected result: StudentId 1 and 3. Note that 2 and 4 are not part of the result because of c

**Solution1:**

If I go with Schema1 then I have to query table "where subject in ('a' , 'b')" which will return all studentIds and I will have have additional logic after fetching the result and discard studentId 2 and 4

And the same with schema2 as well where  i run a LIKE "%a%" or LIKE "%b%" which returns all the result.

I can also create a list of possible combinations to query like 'a' or 'b' or 'a,b' but this combinations set will grow huge if requesting for multiple subjects.

Problem:
Always returns a huge result set which will need additional processing.

**Solution2:**

```
select distinct(StudentId) from schema1 where subject  NOT IN ('c');

select StudentId from schema2 where subjects  NOT LIKE "%c%";
```

Here I can directly fetch only the studentIds as expected but this solution has the below problem

1. Will involve me to know all available subjects
2. Run a query filter with all subjects except for the requested subjects
3. The subject list can grow over time and the query becomes inefficient

**Solution3:**

```
select distinct(StudentId) 
from schema1 where StudentId NOT IN (
    select distinct(StudentId) 
    from schema1 where subject NOT IN ('a', 'b')
);
```

Is there an efficient way to run this query? Or a better schema design that would help with the use case? Is there other database technologies that are better at solving such problems efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

There is no consideration at all.  A *table* represents an entity.  Your data has two entities:  students and subjects.

These entities are connected by an n-m relationship:  any student can have multiple subjects; any subject can have multiple students.

So, you want three tables:

- `students`
- `subjects`
- `studentSubjects`

In relational databases, you do not want to store multiple items in a single column, particularly in a string column.  Of your two options, the first is basically correct, but I would recommend a `subjects` table and numeric ids for `studentId`s and `subjectId`s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking to solve the problem of how to efficiently do a lookup of all the `studentId`s given the `subjectId`s  with some constraints.
>>from original post
>>>
Eg: if I look for students subscribed to subjects a,b then the result should only include students subscribed to a,b or a or b. not a,c or b,c If I run this search in the sample schema provided above then

Expected result: StudentId 1 and 3. Note that 2 and 4 are not part of the result because of c

Comment: @Loik . . . This question appears to be about how to design the database.  If it is also about running queries, then it is too broad for a single question.